# import json into react app but it's undefined when accessing a nested field

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, next.js, next-router

I imported a json file into my react app (using next.js router), and need to access a field in it by a parameter in the URL. It works when I navigate from another page `(/home -> /annotations/<some id>)`, but doesn't work when I refresh the page `(/annotations/<some id>)` or directly access it.

JSON:

```
{
  "page1-9.svg": {
    "points": [
      ...
    ],
    "viewBox": "0 0 191.2066944434739 163.20512234635925"
  },
...
}
```

```
import tangrams from "../../assets/tangrams.json";
//..other imports

export default function Annotations(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const router = useRouter();
  const { tangramId } = router.query;

  console.log(tangrams[tangramId]); // this always works
  console.log(tangrams[tangramId]["viewBox"]); // server error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewBox' of undefined
  return (...
```

If I only access `tangrams[tangramId]`, it works fine, but if I access `tangrams[tangramId]["viewBox"]`, it throws `server error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewBox' of undefined`.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: What is the value of `router.query`? If it is not `"page1-9.svg"` then that would be your issue.

Comment: As `useRouter()` is a hook `router.query` will be undefined when rendering on the server-side. Move the logic where you use `tangramId` to a `useEffect` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searched around, seems to be related to this: [github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11484](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11484)

The query parameter is undefined at the first render...